# How can I lock down panels in sled11?

Tags: linux, sled

I have sled11 and I'm trying to lockdown the panels so others don't change things on it

Please provide full instruction in how to change that

Comment: It would be nicer next time if you asked it politely @Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the Gnome Lockdown section ;-)
You can find the link [here](http://library.gnome.org/admin/deployment-guide/)

Specifically this key:

```
/apps/panel/global/locked_down
```

I have tried using other external programs but none work any better in my experience YMMV